# Horizontal navigation menu - how to increase size of <li> on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a navigation menu. I'm trying to achieve something like that the one on this website: www.fizjoterapia-domkrakow.pl/

I've been searching a lot and I couldn't find a way to increase the size of the

when hovering over it. I'm using jquery(mouseover) to add new class to

that would have a greater size.

Also, there is a ribbon shadow effect on the hovered element that I have no idea how to implement it.

The other problem I have is the opacity of the elements inside the header. I keep the logo inside one div and menu inside the other one. Both of them are in the  that has a background set to opacity:0.9. Unfortunately my logo and menu are also set to such value. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Here is the code sample.

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#about2 li").mouseover(function () {
                $(this).addClass("liOnHover")
            });
            $("#about2 li").mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("liOnHover")
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="menuItems">
            <ul id="about2">
                <li id="contact">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Home")</li>
                <li id="about">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "About")</li>
                <li id="priceList">@Html.ActionLink("PriceList", "PriceList", "Home")</li>
                <li id="reviews">@Html.ActionLink("Reviews", "Reviews", "Home")</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="main">
```

CSS:

```
header {
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #527F9D;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  }


#logo 
{
    padding: 30px 0 20px 70px;
    float: left;
}

#main
{
    margin:20px 210px 20px 210px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.liOnHover
{
    background-Color:#0099FF;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
    box-shadow:         0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block
}

#menuItems {
    width: 900px;
    height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:18px;
    right:20px;
    top:150px;
    left:350px;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: Enriqueta-Bold;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #86ADED;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
    box-shadow:         0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
}

#menuItems ul {
    padding: 2px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#menuItems li {
display: inline;
padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that [CSS has a pseudo class](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/) called `:hover` that has existed since at least CSS 2?

Comment: Yeap, but it still doesn't solve my problem. If I added such class and set it to the styles of liOnHover, it wouldn't help.

Comment: My sentence was a comment, not an answer.  It was only intended to make sure you were aware of an alternative way to use hover, not as an answer to your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. But I think I'll need to add some more javascript code to create that ribbon shadow effect which is displayed after the element has been enlarged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Javascript to achieve this you could simply use the `:hover` attribute in CSS

```
#menuItems li {
   display: inline;
   padding: 4px;
}

#menuItems li:hover {
   background-Color:#0099FF;
   color: white;
   min-height: 100px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
   -moz-box-shadow:    0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
   box-shadow:         0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
   text-align: center;
   display:inline-block
}
```

regarding your second issue, opacity is always influencing the children of the element, if you just want to use a transparent background you could set the color using `background-color: rgba(82,127,157,.9)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the selector `#menuItems li.liOnHover` or `#menuItems li:hover` for the hover changes to work.

Additionally, you should set the `display` of `#menuItems li` to `inline-block`.

Hope this helps.